Cameo - Using a legend to apply adornments to transitions in a state machine diagram
I am looking for a way to automatically format transitions in a state machine diagram in Cameo Systems Modeler.
I am modeling a device with a small display and three buttons (Top, Middle, and Bottom).
Each time one of these buttons is pressed, the display transitions to a different screen represented by a state in my diagram.
I am using signals  called (Top, Middle, and Bottom) for the SignalEvent I'm using as the trigger for each transition.
Is there a way to use a Legend to automatically set all transitions to be color coded based on the button that has been pressed?
(I'm not married to using the signal event, maybe there is a better way to identify transitions for color-coding)
I've tried creating a legend and setting the Apply To -> Elements by Condition to filter elements of Type Transition, but I'm stuck on trying to filter for transitions that use a particular trigger event.
